# Problema com Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR),

Tags: sintaxe

Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro já fiz diversas pesquisas mais ainda n consegui entender o que esta de errado.

```
**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR), expecting ';'

Filename: views/dashboard_view.php

Line Number: 760

Backtrace:**
```

Segue a Linha que apresenta o Erro

```
legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span><%=datasets[i].label%></li><%}%></ul>",
```

**Código em Questão ---EDIT CÓDIGO COMPLETO---**

```js
<script>
            $(function () {

                'use strict';

                /* ChartJS
                 * -------
                 * Here we will create a few charts using ChartJS
                 */

                //-----------------------
                //- MONTHLY SALES CHART -
                //-----------------------

                // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
                var salesChartCanvas = $("#salesChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
                // This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
                var salesChart = new Chart(salesChartCanvas);

                var salesChartData = {
                    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July","August","September","October","November","December"],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "2016",
                            fillColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.9)",
                            strokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.8)",
                            pointColor: "#3b8bba",
                            pointStrokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
                            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
                            data: [
<?php echo $bln1[0]['jumlah']; ?>, 
<?php echo $bln2[0]['jumlah']; ?>, 
<?php echo $bln3[0]['jumlah']; ?>, 
<?php echo $bln4[0]['jumlah']; ?>, 
<?php echo $bln5[0]['jumlah']; ?>, 
<?php echo $bln6[0]['jumlah']; ?>, 
<?php echo $bln7[0]['jumlah']; ?>, 
<?php echo $bln8[0]['jumlah']; ?>, 
<?php echo $bln9[0]['jumlah']; ?>, 
<?php echo $bln10[0]['jumlah']; ?>, 
<?php echo $bln11[0]['jumlah']; ?>, 
<?php echo $bln12[0]['jumlah']; ?>
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };

        var salesChartOptions = {
            //Boolean - If we should show the scale at all
            showScale: true,
            //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
            scaleShowGridLines: false,
            //String - Colour of the grid lines
            scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
            //Number - Width of the grid lines
            scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
            //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
            scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
            //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
            scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
            //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
            bezierCurve: true,
            //Number - Tension of the bezier curve between points
            bezierCurveTension: 0.3,
            //Boolean - Whether to show a dot for each point
            pointDot: false,
            //Number - Radius of each point dot in pixels
            pointDotRadius: 4,
            //Number - Pixel width of point dot stroke
            pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
            //Number - amount extra to add to the radius to cater for hit detection outside the drawn point
            pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
            //Boolean - Whether to show a stroke for datasets
            datasetStroke: true,
            //Number - Pixel width of dataset stroke
            datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
            //Boolean - Whether to fill the dataset with a color
            datasetFill: true,
            //String - A legend template
            legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span><%=datasets[i].label%></li><%}%></ul>",
            //Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
            responsive: true
        };

        //Create the line chart
        salesChart.Line(salesChartData, salesChartOptions);

        //---------------------------
        //- END MONTHLY SALES CHART -
        //---------------------------

        //-------------
        //- PIE CHART -
        //-------------
        // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
        var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
        var PieData = [
            {
                value: <?php echo $Menawarkan[0]['jumlah']; ?>,
                color: "#00a65b",
                highlight: "#E3F2E1",
                label: "Offer"
            },
            {
                value: <?php echo $Mencari[0]['jumlah']; ?>,
                color: "#472bad",
                highlight: "#E3F2E1",
                label: "Search"
            },
            {
                value: <?php echo $Berhasil[0]['jumlah']; ?>,
                color: "#0ba00d",
                highlight: "#E3F2E1",
                label: "Complete"
            },
            {
                value: <?php echo $Ditolak[0]['jumlah']; ?>,
                color: "#f43f3f",
                highlight: "#E3F2E1",
                label: "Rejected"
            },
            {
                value: <?php echo $Dibatalkan[0]['jumlah']; ?>,
                color: "#f43f3f",
                highlight: "#E3F2E1",
                label: "Rejected"
            },
            {
                value: <?php echo $Memulai[0]['jumlah']; ?>,
                color: "#38a0b9",
                highlight: "#E3F2E1",
                label: "Memulai"
            },
            {
                value: <?php echo $Selesai[0]['jumlah']; ?>,
                color: "#0ba00d",
                highlight: "#E3F2E1",
                label: "Complete"
            }
        ];
        var pieOptions = {
            //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
            segmentShowStroke: true,
            //String - The colour of each segment stroke
            segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
            //Number - The width of each segment stroke
            segmentStrokeWidth: 1,
            //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
            percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
            //Number - Amount of animation steps
            animationSteps: 100,
            //String - Animation easing effect
            animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
            //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
            animateRotate: true,
            //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
            animateScale: false,
            //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
            responsive: true,
            // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            //String - A legend template
            legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
            //String - A tooltip template
            tooltipTemplate: "<%=value %> <%=label%>"
        };
        //Create pie or douhnut chart
        // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
        pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
        //-----------------
        //- END PIE CHART -
        //-----------------

        /* jVector Maps
         * ------------
         * Create a world map with markers
         */
        $('#world-map-markers').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill_en',
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
            hoverOpacity: 0.7,
            hoverColor: false,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            regionStyle: {
                initial: {
                    fill: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                    "fill-opacity": 1,
                    stroke: 'none',
                    "stroke-width": 0,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                },
                hover: {
                    "fill-opacity": 0.7,
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                },
                selected: {
                    fill: 'yellow'
                },
                selectedHover: {}
            },
            markerStyle: {
                initial: {
                    fill: '#3a5068',
                    stroke: '#111'
                }
            },
            markers: [
                {latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City'},
                {latLng: [43.73, 7.41], name: 'Monaco'},
                {latLng: [-0.52, 166.93], name: 'Nauru'},
                {latLng: [-8.51, 179.21], name: 'Tuvalu'},
                {latLng: [43.93, 12.46], name: 'San Marino'},
                {latLng: [47.14, 9.52], name: 'Liechtenstein'},
                {latLng: [7.11, 171.06], name: 'Marshall Islands'},
                {latLng: [17.3, -62.73], name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis'},
                {latLng: [3.2, 73.22], name: 'Maldives'},
                {latLng: [35.88, 14.5], name: 'Malta'},
                {latLng: [12.05, -61.75], name: 'Grenada'},
                {latLng: [13.16, -61.23], name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines'},
                {latLng: [13.16, -59.55], name: 'Barbados'},
                {latLng: [17.11, -61.85], name: 'Antigua and Barbuda'},
                {latLng: [-4.61, 55.45], name: 'Seychelles'},
                {latLng: [7.35, 134.46], name: 'Palau'},
                {latLng: [42.5, 1.51], name: 'Andorra'},
                {latLng: [14.01, -60.98], name: 'Saint Lucia'},
                {latLng: [6.91, 158.18], name: 'Federated States of Micronesia'},
                {latLng: [1.3, 103.8], name: 'Singapore'},
                {latLng: [1.46, 173.03], name: 'Kiribati'},
                {latLng: [-21.13, -175.2], name: 'Tonga'},
                {latLng: [15.3, -61.38], name: 'Dominica'},
                {latLng: [-20.2, 57.5], name: 'Mauritius'},
                {latLng: [26.02, 50.55], name: 'Bahrain'},
                {latLng: [0.33, 6.73], name: 'São Tomé and Príncipe'}
            ]
        });

        /* SPARKLINE CHARTS
         * ----------------
         * Create a inline charts with spark line
         */

        //-----------------
        //- SPARKLINE BAR -
        //-----------------
        $('.sparkbar').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.sparkline('html', {
                type: 'bar',
                height: $this.data('height') ? $this.data('height') : '30',
                barColor: $this.data('color')
            });
        });

        //-----------------
        //- SPARKLINE PIE -
        //-----------------
        $('.sparkpie').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.sparkline('html', {
                type: 'pie',
                height: $this.data('height') ? $this.data('height') : '90',
                sliceColors: $this.data('color')
            });
        });

        //------------------
        //- SPARKLINE LINE -
        //------------------
        $('.sparkline').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.sparkline('html', {
                type: 'line',
                height: $this.data('height') ? $this.data('height') : '90',
                width: '100%',
                lineColor: $this.data('linecolor'),
                fillColor: $this.data('fillcolor'),
                spotColor: $this.data('spotcolor')
            });
        });
    });
    
</script>
```

Comment: Possivelmente está faltando um `;` no seu código.

Coloque o `views/dashboard_view.php` aqui para podermos analisar.

Comment: Editei o POST coloquei o código completo !
Separando as linha apresenta o erro aqui **<% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%>**

Comment: Não encontrei nada que pareça fora do lugar, provavelmente o erro está estourando em outro lugar. Já testou mudar o `legendTemplate` para uma string vazia? Só para termos certeza se o erro é ou não ali.

Comment: Esses valores que você cospe via php são de que tipo?

Comment: Analizando o Script em **phpcodechecker** ele apresenta o erro só aqui **legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span><%=datasets[i].label%></li><%}%>/ul>",**

Comment: Mudando legendTemplate  para vazia apresenta o erro em outra linha que tem o mesmo código , se eu remover da outra linha, ai ja n da mais erro de Sintaxe @MarlonBahniuk

Answer (score 0):

Por Hora resolvi o problema com uma solução provisória! Como posso evitar o conflito definitivamente?

Problema é que **<%** e **%>** é interpretado como código ASP.NET, a solução foi alterar usar uma representação diferente para os caracteres **%** usei **\x25**

**Código Original**

```js
legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span><%=datasets[i].label%></li><%}%></ul>",
```

**Código Editado**

```js
legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<\x25=name.toLowerCase()\x25>-legend\"><\x25 for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){\x25><li><span style=\"background-color:<\x25=datasets[i].lineColor\x25>\"></span><\x25=datasets[i].label\x25></li><\x25}\x25></ul>",
```

Reparem que ao invés de **%** eu utilizei **\x25**

Alguém sabe como eu posso evitar o conflito definitivamente?

Comment: vc usa php com asp tags (`<% %>`)?

Comment: Pra ser sincero nem sei, pois novato em PHP.

Comment: No php vc usa `<?php e ?>` asp tag e outras não são recomendadas há mais de 10 anos. Dê uma olhada no change log => http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php